# Can I use wubi if I have a UEFI motherboard and Windows Vista?

Tags: boot, windows, wubi, uefi, windows-vista

Am I safe if I am not using Windows 8?

Also, I built the computer myself, it was not a computer pre-built with Windows 8.

Comment: Normally, yes, but you have to know that there isn't any warranty with Ubuntu, neither I'm not sure.

Comment: what do you mean "neither I'm not sure"?

Comment: Everyone that use ubuntu know what he means with that ;). It can take some time to get used of it. But "nothing happends in a wonder" when you install ubuntu ;).

Comment: Okay, I was not sure if it was complete waste of time to try to mess with wubi on a uefi mobo. Hopefully it goes well when I try it.

Comment: Also, as I am reading, I am finding out that I don't want to use wubi, I want to just create two partitions and install ubuntu on one and vista on another...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The last I heard, WUBI was *not* compatible with EFI-mode booting. Thus, if your Windows is installed in EFI mode, you should *not* attempt a WUBI install, since it will be a waste of time at best.

That said, just because a motherboard supports EFI doesn't mean that it's necessarily booting using EFI. If you install Windows in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode, you should be able to use WUBI. You can check your Windows boot mode by examining the partition table: If it uses the older [Master Boot Record (MBR)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record) system, Windows is installed in BIOS mode; if it uses the newer [GUID Partition Table (GPT)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table) system, Windows is installed in EFI mode.

You can install Linux side-by-side with Windows in a traditional non-WUBI way in either BIOS or EFI mode, so as a general rule, that's the safest way to proceed. If you're building the computer from scratch, that's likely to be the better way to go; WUBI is best used if you're not certain you want to keep Linux and if you don't want to bother repartitioning. You should learn about BIOS vs. EFI boot modes in Linux to ensure you install Linux in a compatible way. One quick check is to open a Terminal or switch to a text-mode console and look for the directory `/sys/firmware/efi`. If it's present, you've booted Linux in EFI mode, and the installation program will attempt an EFI-mode installation. If that directory is absent, you've probably booted in BIOS mode and the installer will attempt a BIOS-mode installation.

Answer (score 1):

There are wubi installers for UEFI systems. I am currently running a 16.04 installation with Windows 10.

What these installers do is dump grub into an EFI partition (E: as described on my computer) which is addressable from the UEFI firmware, and boots and mounts the disk images on your Windows partition.

https://github.com/hakuna-m/wubiuefi/wiki

First, download the iso, and then run the installer in the same directory as the iso.

Hope this helps.

ps: as with all wubi installations there are inherent weaknesses in wubi which make it generally undesirable. Fortunately, I'm lazy and don't care, although I should.

Comment: **E: partition** should be **EFI partition**. I also installed the Wubi for UEFI systems. In my install log I found a temporary EFI drive H: which was assigned to my EFI boot partition \Device\HarddiskVolume2. There is no **E:**.  But that doesn't change the main statement of your answer. So it it is still useful.  Even if someone uses Windows Vista and don't know if he really uses UEFI.  Wubiuefi works also on Windows which doesn't use UEFI.